# iframe as a div background with visible content inside and clickable

Tags: html, css, iframe, background, vimeo

I have to set a Vimeo as background for a div which is containing CTA box.
I found some example and made it possible to have the video background fullscreen and responsive as I needed.
But I found that the CTA box inside and the button are not clickable because of the "z-index" used to get the video back in the div.

play with z-index
moving element back and forth

```css
.vimeo-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display:flex;
   pointer-events: none;
   overflow: hidden;
  
}
.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 56.25vw; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 9/16*100 = 56.25 */
   min-height: 100vh;
   min-width: 177.77vh; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 16/9*100 = 177.77 */
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   
}.content{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  z-index:1;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}.content,h2{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
 .CTA-wrapper{
  border:2px solid white;
  width:30%;
  padding-bottom:2%;
   
}
div button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/342964528?     background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="CTA-wrapper">
      <h2>CTA Header</h2>
      <button class="btn-success">Click Me</button>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

expected: clickable inside elements, fullscreen and responsive background video
result: not the clickable inside element

Comment: Answer below fixed the button issue, but still, have other problem as the video is the background of the whole site and entire page. it must be inside its <div> and  other elements before it's <div> should be visible

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

**css**

```
.vimeo-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display:flex;
   pointer-events: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.content,h2{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}
 .CTA-wrapper{
  border:2px solid white;
  padding-bottom:2%;

}
.vimeo-wrapper-box {
    width: 100%;
}
div button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.iframe_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.vimeo-wrapper .content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
    <div class="vimeo-wrapper-box">
        <h1>dfghfh</h1>
        <div class="iframe_wrapper">
           <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/342964528?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="CTA-wrapper">
                  <h2>CTA Header</h2>
                  <button class="btn-success">Click Me</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this fixed the issue but the Video is background of entire page and not only the div.

Comment: <div class="container">
  <h1>test</h1> if you wrappe the previous code in the this container and get a <h1> befor it but inside the outer container, the you can not see the h1

Comment: .content, h2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
} As u are added color:#white.. the text is showing.. change the color and check

Comment: I didn't say that h2 is invisible. the color is white already. if you use another element before iframe, then you don't see that. I want iframe full width inside its div, not the whole page width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.CTA-wrapper{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9999;
}
```